# subfig.sty missing in MikTEX?

Tags: subfig

I installed MikTeX miktex-2.9.6650-1-darwin-x86_64.dmg on macOS. The subfig.sty seems to be missing, see error message below. Never had problems before. Is subfig.sty really missing?

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6650)
entering extended mode
(mzTab2TAILSreport_temp.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 0 language(s) loaded.
("/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/base/article.cls
"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/base/size10.clo"
))

! LaTeX Error: File `subfig.sty' not found.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! It is not installed by default by the basic installer. Launch `MiKTeX Console` and select `Packages` (you can filter the list of packages entering part of the name).

Comment: I was under the impression that MikTeX (Windows, not Mac) could automatically detect missing *.sty files, know which package was needed, and install them on-the-fly. Does that not happen in Mac? Or is it a matter of configuring the behavior of MikTeX?

Comment: I can confirm that the behaviour of MikTeX under Windows is different. There, subfig.sty is downloaded on the fly, or installed by default.

Comment: Using MikTeX console, under Settings/General click "Always install packages on the fly."

Answer (score 1):

Using MikTeX console, under Settings/General click "Always install packages on the fly."